Selenium webdriver chrome in Mobaxterm
def get_generic_name(drug_name):
    driver=None
    try:
        # Specify the path to the Chrome WebDriver
        webdriver_path = "/home/ksamira/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver"  # Update this with the actual path
        service = Service(webdriver_path)
        
        # Set up Chrome options
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
        options.add_argument("start-maximized")

        # Initialize the WebDriver with options
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
        
        # Navigate to the DrugBank website
        driver.get("https://go.drugbank.com/drugs")

        # Find the search box by ID and type the drug name
        search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "query"))
        )
        search_box.send_keys(drug_name)
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        # Wait for the element to be present
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".col-xl-4.col-md-9.col-sm-8.pr-xl-2"))
        )

        # Extract the text from the element
        generic_name = element.text
    except TimeoutException:
        print(f"Timeout error for drug '{drug_name}': Element not found within the specified time")
        generic_name = "Not Found"
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print(f"Element not found for drug '{drug_name}': {str(e)}")
        generic_name = "Not Found"
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error for drug '{drug_name}': {str(e)}")
        generic_name = "Not Found"
    finally:
        # Close the browser
        driver.quit()
    return generic_name

Hello, I am doing webscraping with python. I am working on Mobaxterm. The server used is : narval. The erro message I got is :  Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
and AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'quit'
. I think the problem is the location of the chrome binary file. I had this file in my computer which is a Windows. I don't know how to make it available on Mobaxterm. I just start using selenium on Mobaxterm. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you
